# How do I set a default value in a model without having a column for it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, default-value

I am trying to set a default value to a property in my model

```
public string fruitType = "Apple";
public string FruitType
{
    get { return fruitType; }
    set { fruitType = value; }
}
```

The issue that I am having however is `FruitType` isn't a column in my database table, so it is throwing an error. Is it possible for me to set this even though the column does not exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark your property as `NotMapped` and use the default value :

```
public string fruitType = "Apple";
[NotMapped]
public string FruitType
{
    get { return fruitType; }
    set { fruitType = value ?? fruitType; }
}
```